# Find and add the velocity of a Rigidbody that's directly below another? (Unity + C#)

Tags: c#, .net, 2d, platform

I have an issue that I've not been able to solve for a few days now and without it working I can't move on with my project, so your help would be greatly appreciated!

What I'm trying to do is 'find' the velocity of an object that is directly below my 2D sprite (that also contains a Rigidbody and 2D box collider) and then add that velocity (in the same direction) to the object that is 'looking' for it.

I feel like ray-casting might be part of the answer but I'm not sure how to use that, especially in this context.

The idea behind this is I have a platform that can carry objects stacked on top of each other, so you move the mouse, it manipulates the platforms velocity, but this causes the objects on-top to fly backwards, no mater how high the friction is.

Here is the platform code:

```
void Update()
{

    float distance_to_screen = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(gameObject.transform.position).z;

    Vector3 pos_move = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, distance_to_screen));

    mouseDelta = pos_move - lastMousePosition;

    acceleration = mouseDelta.x * 0.4f;
    platformVelocity += acceleration;
    platform.velocity = new Vector2(platformVelocity, 0) * speed;

    lastMousePosition = pos_move;

}
```

Thank you for taking the time to read this, I would very much appreciate any help you can give!

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary to 'find' that object? 'Finding' may be difficult & costing.

Can you hold the 'below-thing' reference and pass it to 'above-thing'?

Comment: Yeah, that'd be great if knew how, as I said I think ray casting might be the key, I just don't know how to use it. Finding would be very costly and it wouldn't help because I'd have to find by tag or something and all of the objects will have the same tag.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have some method on objects that checks whether it's on a moving platform. One option is to add an IsOnMovingPlatform flag on those objects. Then use a similar method to check if any object is on top of the "IsOnMovingPlatform == true" objects. Keep doing passes on that method until you don't come up with any more flags set to true.

Comment: Not right now I don't, but I did try something similar to that which used the 2D box colliders, but that caused problems when the boxes were hit by the ones above it and caused it to say that it's no-longer touching the one below. Any ideas for ray casting at all instead?

Comment: The problem I foresee with raycasting is how do you distinguish between an object that is on (i.e. above + touching) the moving platform and one that may be above it but resting on a different platform, or even just moving above it, as if it were thrown? It still comes down to whether or not the object is touching the platform or objects on it.

Comment: Well as I understand it, ray casts can be used to find an object in any direction, so you can just have it only find what's directly below something.

Comment: Right, but if an object is being thrown over the moving platform, or if the point on the object you're raycasting from is hanging over the edge of a platform above the moving platform, it still will find the moving platform in the raycast.

Comment: True, but not if you have just one ray pointing down from the very center downwards (as in, always down, no mater what the rotation is), then it would work for what I need.

Answer (score 0):

So, i'm trying to understand your question and I think I might know what you're talking about. 
Are you saying that you want your game object (2d sprite) to stay on the platform as its moving? I have had the same problem, where a platform is moving and my player (game object) slides off- and this is how I fixed it.

Add a box collider to the platform (trigger). When the player enters the platform, make the player's transform the platform. That way, when the platform moves- the player moves with it no matter what the speed is.

For example:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2d collider){
if(collider.tag.equals("Player")){ // you only want the player to work
 // attach script to platform for "this.transform" to work
   collider.transform.SetParent(this.transform); 

 }
}
```

then, to unparent the transform "otherwise, even when the player is off the platform, it will move with the platform.

```
void OnTriggerExit(Collider2d collider){
// assuming your player isn't supposed to have a parent!
    collider.transform.parent = null;
}
```

Sorry if I misunderstood your question! If this is what you were going for, finding the velocity of the platform is not necessary. Also, this is uncompiled code- if you have issues let me know.

EDIT:

To add a bit of a give, for the entire duration that the player is in contact with the platform, we can add a little bit of a negative force to shove the player a little bit!

We do this by using OnTriggerStay2D (assuming your game is 2d, otherwise use OnTriggerStay).

For example:

```
void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2d collider){
  if(collider.tag.equals("Player")){
    collider.getComponent<Rigidbody2D>().addForce(new vector2(forceToAdd, 0));
  }
}
```

now, that "forceToAdd" variable should be based on the speed and direction that your platform is going. Does your platform have a rigid body on it? if so you can get your force variable by retrieving the rigid body from the platform (getcomponent()) and get the X velocity from it. With this velocity, experiment with dividing it by numbers until you find a good fit, multiply it by -1 (because you want to push the player in the opposite direction of the platform travel), then this will be your forceToAdd!

However, if your platform is not using a Rigidbody, then a way you can do this is record the x positions in your script (just two positions, and subtract these to find the distance in an update method), multiply by -1, try dividing by a number (experiment with this) and that can be your force to add variable.

Also, my code for the OnTriggerStay2d is rough, the spelling could be a bit wrong- but this will give you a rough idea for a solution! ALSO.. I don't think getting the component of a rigid body should be done in every frame, a way around this would to have your rigid body component as a global variable in the script, then set your rigid body on OnTriggerEnter2d, this way it will only retrieve it once (instead of every frame) which I assume would be more efficient!

Good luck! and if you have any questions il try to help!

Comment: Hi Bryan, thanks for the help. Unfortunately I've already tried this solution, but it doesn't work how I need it. One reason is because I don't want them locked dead on the platform, I want there to be a little bit of give because it's a physics based thing. And the other reason is there are multiple objects that will stack up on each other, so I need them to sway a little, so if I parse in most of the objects speed from below, but not all of it, it will give the effect I require.

Comment: Ah! I see, that makes sense! Well, il edit my original answer to give a little bit of a give! An alternative to my answer would be to raycast directly down, a raycast that goes directly down is used often to ensure a player can't jump if they're not touching the ground. Try out my modified answer that il edit right now, play around with the values and see if it fits your purposes- if not then look in to raycasts, theres loads of examples out there!

Comment: Hey Bryan! I really appreciate your efforts here, you're a champion! I'm having trouble understanding how this method knows to look for the one it's touching from below, without looking for the ones touching it from other sides (like above)? Because all of the objects will have the same tags as each other (some are even duplicates of the same object). Also if I use Trigger instead of Collision, I'd need to have a child inside of the object, wouldn't I? I tried using Collision (because they're rigidbody objects that are not set as triggers) but it's giving an error for this line "getComponent"

Comment: No problem! :) These methods only know when something is inside its trigger box collider, the line "tag.equals("Player")" ensures that it's the player thats in the box (this is assuming you have set your player's tag to "Player"!) So these methods will only run when some object (with a rigid body) lands on the platforms. To get Trigger to work all you need to do is have the box collider on your platform a trigger collider(theres a little checkbox), and have your player have a rigid body and collider (which I'm sure you already have). Make sure the OnTriggerEnter methods are spelt correctly-

Comment: As if they are misspelt then they won't be called! Try adding a print statement to see if the methods are running. There is no need for a child object. Yes I believe I misspelt getComponent, I think it is GetComponent. You use that line when you want to get access to a component on a game object! For example, you want the player's rigid body to add forces to so you can write, Rigidbody rbdy = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

Comment: Also, please note when using GetComponent : it gets the component of the GameObject that you are currently referencing! So if you have a script ATTACHED to a player, then you can just write GetComponent<Rigidbody>(); to reference the Rigidbody, it you have a script attached to a DIFFERENT game object, then you must add the game object whose component you want to access before get component, for example: player.GetComponent<Rigidbody>(); where 'player' is your player GameObject. Hope this helped!

Comment: Alright I think I get what you're trying to suggest now, I really value the help you're giving me btw! If I understand correctly, to get the object below the current one, I'd need to have a separate box collider attached to the bottom of the object that is a trigger, right? If that's the case, I'm not sure it will work, because the objects that stack on top of each-other can rotate (they're boxes and they roll sometimes). How would I accomplish this with my current setup? Would raycast be the only way?

Comment: So to get this to work you would need a trigger box collider on every platform, I would expand the box collider so it sticks out just a little bit so it would register the player stepping on it easier. Also the script would have to be on every platform as the script is checking to see if the player is on its respective platform. If the boxes are rotating and you only want them to be able to walk on the top of them (whatever side is up) I suppose raycasting would be a bit easier. While it is possible to use my script to see if the player is on the top of the box, it might be a pain.

Comment: Is your game 2D? I have used raycasting a few times but never in 2D, I'm not sure if the rules are different- but basically you would want to shoot a ray from the players feet directly down 5 units or so, il add another answer :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a raycast2d version, I tested it and it works much better than the trigger collider version :).

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

```
public class RaycastFeetDeleteLater : MonoBehaviour {

[SerializeField] private float raycastDist = 0.1f;
[SerializeField] Transform feet;
[SerializeField] private float xForceDampener = 0.1f;
private Rigidbody2D rb2d;


// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate () {
    RaycastDown ();
}

private void RaycastDown(){
    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast (feet.position, Vector2.down, raycastDist);
    if (hit.collider != null) {
        print (hit.transform.tag);
        if (hit.collider.tag.Equals ("Platform")) {
            transform.SetParent (hit.transform);
            Vector2 force = new Vector2 ((hit.transform.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity.x * xForceDampener) * -1, 0);
            print (force);
            rb2d.AddForce (force);
        } else if (transform.parent != null) {
            print ("UNPARENT");
            transform.parent = null;
        } 
    } else {
        if (transform.parent != null) {
            transform.parent = null;
        }
    }
    Debug.DrawRay (feet.position, Vector3.down, Color.green, raycastDist);

  }
}
```

This script is attached to the player! No need to have scripts on the platforms, which was the main reason my previous method was a pain :P

Basically this script does the following:
- Gets rigidbody2d of the player on start (we will be adding forces to the player with it soon, so might as well store it in a variable!

- On FixedUpdate (Different than Update, FixedUpdate is called on Physics update, where as Update is called every frame) I have read that raycast should use FixedUpdate, I suppose because it is a Physics method!
- RaycastDown shoots a 2D raycast directly down from the feet position (to get the feet, create a child object of the player, put the position of the feet a tiny bit below the player, NOT ON THE PLAYER- I will explain why in a second why that will mess up everything! Then drag the feet GameObject on to the "feet" slot of the script.)
- Raycast shoots from feet directly down at a distance that is changeable in the editor (raycastDist) I found a distance of 0.1f was perfect for my needs, but play around with it for yours! You can actually see a drawing of your Ray by using Debug.DrawRay as seen in the code, the ray is only visible in the editor- not game view! But this will help, especially with positioning the feet.
- Checks if it hit an object with a collider, if so check if the objects tag is a Platform (set the platforms to a new tag and call it Platform).
- If it hits a platform set the parent of the player to the platform (like the last script) and start applying a little force to the player in the negative direction that the platform is traveling (we get the rigid body of the platform to find its velocity).
- If the raycast does not hit a platform, unparent it so the player can move freely.

Thats basically it, however...
Please note:

- This script needs to be on the player, not any of the players child objects, since this script will unparent the player from any platforms- if you have the script on a child object of the player it will unparent from the player- which is horrible. So The script MUST be on the root game object of the player. There are ways around this if for some reason you can't.
- As mentioned before, the "feet" child object must be a little bit under the player- this is because when the Raycast2d "fires" it will find the FIRST object with a collider it hits- so if you have the start of the raycast hit a collider on the player then it will always show the raycast hitting the player, not a platform. So to get around this have the raycast fire from the feet- and have the feet position a tiny bit below the player. To help with this I added a print statement that will print to the console which object the raycast is hitting, if it doesn't say "Platform" then you need to lower the feet! :)
- Furthermore, I'm not sure how you are moving your platforms- but if the Velocity of the platform always prints "0,0" then its because you are moving the platforms position directly, instead of moving it by forces (this happened to me when I was testing this script). I got around this by moving the platform by "AddForce". Also depending on the "Mass" of your platforms, you may need to drastically increase the "xForceDampener" which I should of actually labeled "xForceMultiplier" as I found while testing I needed to set it much higher- like at 60, instead of 0.25 which I previously thought would be okay..

Hope this helped :D

EDIT: Linking the unity docs for 2D Raycasts in case you need
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html

Comment: Wow that's a lot of information to process! Thanks Bryan! I also really appreciate your xForceDampener comment, I think I will definitely need it soon. As for the raycast thing, it looks great, but I actually don't have a "player" per se, what I have is a platform that is what the player controls at the bottom of the screen, their job is to keep the boxes (that fall from the top) on the platform and stack them up. So I think the script probably should be going on each box and a raycast pointing (relative to the world) downwards at all times. Sorry if I confused you before. I appreciate this!

Comment: Also the platform moves with rigidbody.velocity, I made a platform variable be = to the rigidbody in the script in my first question. If you need that part I'll gladly send it over. Thanks again for your help Bryan!

Comment: No problem! :) Good luck! Yeah just put the script on any object that you want to stick to the platforms.

Comment: Do you know how I could make the raycast point downwards relative to the world? Because the blocks I would attach this script to are able to rotate.

Comment: Okay! So in that case don't make a GameObject for "feet", instead of RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast (feet.position, Vector2.down, raycastDist); do this:   RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast (new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y - 5f), Vector2.down, raycastDist);

5f is an estimation, you'l have to play around with it so that the raycast starts right outside of your box, debug.drawyray will help!

Basically instead of having a feet game object, which will rotate with the cube and therefore not always point down- just get the position of your cube, and move the Y

Comment: variable down a set amount so that the raycast starts under the cube.

Comment: Alright, I've tried this, but for some reason the console will tell me that it is touching the platform, and it's location, but the objects never get childed, it also doesn't make the blocks stick more together. Did you mention having a project file that works? Would you mind sending it to me so I can see what mistakes I'm making? My email is s_byrnes@live.com.au - I really appreciate all of your help here Bryan, I'm sorry it's such a stuff around.